# Video player not work in WebView

Tags: android, webview

i need help, my WebView not show website's video player(black square)
But, it is working on phone browser.
Also, i have tried to use some advanced webview from github, same result(balck square).

This my code

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");


    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");

    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("wp-android-native");
    //webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; HTC One X Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.58 Mobile Safari/537.31");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    //webView.setInitialScale(100);


    webView.loadUrl("http://onlinemoviesbox.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please comment below line and check once , am able to play youtube video properly

```
// webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("wp-android-native");
```

Comment: @PavelPoley : Can you please provide a sample video URL ?

Comment: @PavelPoley : i have registered and tried to login in mobile but am getting "unauthorised access" error

Comment: No need to register, you have section "Free movies"

Comment: @PavelPoley somehow without registering am not able to play video in desktop and it shows black square , but once i register am able to play videos .. is this is a expected scenario ?